# Seek in buffered reader

Tags: go

I need to create a buffered reader of an existing child `io.Reader`, but that reader must support seeking in data already read and buffered from the child.

So when `n` bytes were already read, I want to be able to reset the reader to offset `0` and read that chunk again.

Unfortunately `bufio.Reader` doesn't support seeking.

Is there a standard reader that supports this, or do I have to implement my own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of `bufio` is to provide buffered I/O. Buffered I/O is intended for performance, not time travel.

You can just read your data into a byte slice, then use [`bytes.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) to process it further.

Comment: Unfortunately the files I need to read are relatively large multipart files that are read in chunks, that's why I can't use `bytes.Reader` (would need to load everything into memory). Seems I need to use a custom implementation then.

Comment: @ErikAigner: How did it go with the custom implementation? I'm in a similar situation, needing to peek into a `io.Reader` byte stream of CSV data to detect the delimiter before passing the reader into `csv.NewReader()`.

Comment: This is pretty disappointing. [Rust’s `BufReader` supports seeking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#impl-Seek), and I don’t see any reason that Go’s shouldn’t. Often we want buffering for performance, and also want to be able to seek ahead. What’s wrong with that?

Comment: @wchargin Rust's `BufReader<R>` only implements `Seek` if the underlying `R` also implements `Seek`. Go's type system is too weak to express this constraint. Peeking is not the same as seeking; Go's `bufio.Reader` does have `Peek` which lets you peek as far ahead as the buffer size (I think). To seek in Go, if you have the underlying `io.Reader` and you somehow know that it's also an `io.Seeker`, you can always discard the `bufio.Reader`, seek the underlying `io.ReadSeeker` and create a new `bufio.Reader` to wrap it.

Comment: @Thomas: Good point, thanks; I didn’t realize that Go’s type system was too weak to express the constraint. Though it seems that seeking to the underlying reader lets you implement `Seek` from `io.SeekStart`/`io.SeekEnd`, but not `io.SeekCurrent`, and in particular doesn’t let you implement `ftell` without requiring references to _both_ readers with something like `underlying.Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent) - bufReader.Buffered()`.

Comment: @wchargin: If you seek the underlying reader, the buffered reader will not know about it, so subsequent reads from the buffered reader will return data from the wrong position until its buffer is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I wondered if seeking in the opened `os.File` and then using `bufio.Reset()` was an answer, and it sort of is, but not ideal. First of all, the documentation of `bufio.Reset` says it "discards any buffered data", but then again, doesn't the operating system also cache recently read file contents?

Secondly, it works correctly in the sense that the bufio starts reading and buffering from the designated file position, but it doesn't consider sector alignment: it buffers a whole buffer at a time, irrespective of the starting point. Thus, assuming the buffer size (which is 4096 by default) equals the file system's cluster size, and unless the starting point is aligned to clusters, bufio will read from 2 clusters every time it needs to read. I'm not saying that the impact on performance is noticeable. In fact, by reading ahead as much as possible, performance maybe be better than what my alignment obsession might yield.

I think this code demonstrates this, reading a few 2000 byte chunks from the executable itself:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func readBytes(r *bufio.Reader, block []byte) {
    for i := 1; i < len(block); i++ {
        var err error
        block[i], err = r.ReadByte()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

func status(f *os.File, r *bufio.Reader, block []byte, what string) {
    fpos, err := f.Seek(0, os.SEEK_CUR)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s: fpos=%5d, buffered=%4d, md5=%X\n", what, fpos, r.Buffered(), md5.Sum(block))
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[0])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer func() { f.Close() }()
    r := bufio.NewReader(f)
    var block = make([]byte, 2000)
    status(f, r, block, "initial")
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 1")
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 2")
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 3")
    f.Seek(2000, os.SEEK_SET) // return to start of buf1a
    r.Reset(f)
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 2")
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 3")
    readBytes(r, block)
    status(f, r, block, "block 4")
}
```

typical output (showing that after seeking, file position doesn't return to a multiple of 4096):

```
initial: fpos=    0, buffered=   0, md5=CF40A1DE3F93B4A025409B5EFA5AA210
block 1: fpos= 4096, buffered=2096, md5=C7015DD984AB85CCCBD206BA8243647D
block 2: fpos= 4096, buffered=  96, md5=E0D75F4A6DE681316515F5CD53F0D95C
block 3: fpos= 8192, buffered=2192, md5=7961B1A889E9793344374B3022314CD0
block 2: fpos= 6096, buffered=2096, md5=E0D75F4A6DE681316515F5CD53F0D95C
block 3: fpos= 6096, buffered=  96, md5=7961B1A889E9793344374B3022314CD0
block 4: fpos=10192, buffered=2192, md5=2A2F77C23EF4651E630855D9C3AA29DE
```

Comment: This is a partial answer, but one purpose of `Seek` is to determine the current position into the file (`ftell(3)` is implemented in Go as `Seek(0, io.SeekCurrent)`). A proper buffered reader [can implement this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87d9a2d749a32f631ad4c2d15439c2ee), but it can’t be done if you only have access to the underlying file—as you can see from your example, where `fpos` sees only the buffered values.